# OS X Mountain Lion with Psycopg2 (Symbol not found: _PyMemoryView_Type)

Tags: python, django, psycopg2, osx-mountain-lion

I've been stuck on this problem for the past few days, which is preventing me from getting my local environment set up properly. Here's my setup:

- Using OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion
- Via homebrew I have Python and PostgreSQL installed.
- In a Virtualenv, I have Django installed with psycopg2 2.4.5 via PIP
- I've verified that I can connect to my PostgreSQL database via pgAdmin3

However, whenever I spin up my Apache server and navigate to my local URL, I'm greeted with this ugly error:

```
dlopen({....}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): 
Symbol not found: _PyMemoryView_Type

Referenced from: {....}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
Expected in: flat namespace in {....}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
```

Here are the results when I install psycopg2:

```
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.4.5.tar.gz (719Kb): 719Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
    ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
    ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
    ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -Os -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o
    In file included from psycopg/typecast.c:179:
    ./psycopg/typecast_array.c:227:31: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                if (--stack_index < 0)
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
    1 warning generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/X11/lib -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.so

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
Successfully installed psycopg2
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this? I'm stumped and am in desperate need of some help. Thanks in advance. Let me know if any more info would be helpful.

---

Here is my vhost file for Apache:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost mysite.local:80>
    ServerName mysite.local

    Alias /assets/ {...}/app/webapp/assets/
    Alias /static/ {...}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/
    Alias /robots.txt {...}/app/webapp/assets/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico {...}/app/webapp/assets/favicon.ico

    CustomLog "{...}/logs/apache-access.log" combined
    ErrorLog "{...}/logs/apache-error.log"
    LogLevel warn

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.local processes=1 threads=1 maximum-requests=1 python-path={...}/lib/python2.7/site-packages python-eggs={...}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite.local
    WSGIScriptAlias / {...}/conf/apache/django.wsgi
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory {...}/app/webapp/assets>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    <Directory {...}/conf/apache>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Here is my django.wsgi file:

```
import os, sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import site

sys.path.append('{...}/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('{...}/app')
sys.path.append('{...}/app/webapp')
sys.path.append('{...}/app/webapp/apps')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'webapp.settings.production'

site.addsitedir('{...}/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of dancing around with files and settings, I finally figured it out. Largely thanks to @BigHandsome for steering me in the right direction. In my Apache httpd.conf file, I was using the mod_wsgi.so that came with OS X 10.8. Apparently this was the problem. I fixed it by doing the following:

1. Used Homebrew to install a new version of mod_wsgi.so (`brew install mod_wsgi`)
2. At first, Homebrew threw me an error related to Mountain Lion and mod_wsgi. I followed the symlink directions on this reported issue:
   https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13919
3. After symlinking the files detailed in the link, I redid `brew install mod_wsgi` and it worked.
4. I updated my httpd.conf with: `LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/Cellar/mod_wsgi/3.3/libexec/mod_wsgi.so`
5. I restarted Apache2 (`apachectl restart`) and voila!

Answer (score 0):

It is ussually standard to see some c warnings when compiling a package for python on MAC OSX because it uses clang and not gcc.  They should not be the issue.  The issue looks like your WSGI HTTPD setup.

With WSGI and virtual environment and WSGI, you need to make sure that you set up the process environment correctly.

It looks like you need to alter your HTTPD directive to include your processing environment. See Virtual Environments in WSGI, section entitled [Process Environments](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments#Process_Environments).

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. It looks like I already had one of the recommended ways to add my Process Environment via python-path=. I've added two more files to my original post for further info. Any other ideas based on the additional info provided? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I could be a couple thing, let me test your setup.

Answer (score 0):

This was plaguing me as well.  Make sure you've got mod_wsgi built for the proper version of python.

Turned out I had built mod_wsgi for python2.6 but my virtualenv running the website is using python2.7.  I am using macports so the following worked for me:

```
sudo port uninstall mod_wsgi
sudo port install mod_wsgi +python2.7
```

Then restarting apache.

OS X 10.7.3 w/ MacPorts

Check out the following line in your error.log when Apache starts to see which version of Python you're using:

```
[notice] Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
```